# How to add right click menu to IE?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I have done some research and the way to do it use to add it to the registry, but I want to it only appear when the user opens my program which uses the webrowser control. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Do you implement the right-click behavior in a Javascript function, or somewhere else?

Comment: Well Ideally I would prefer not injecting javascript code into the page. There is a context menu and I want change the options of the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

When you press right mouse click than oncontextmenu event is created by browser,

if browser not found any user attached event with this event than it'll disaply its own menu.

but you want to disply your own menu

than use following code

```
YOUR_ELEMENT.AttachEvent('oncontextmenu', INVOKE_METHOD_WHEN_EVENT_OCCURED);

function INVOKE_METHOD_WHEN_EVENT_OCCURED(e)
{

...
  var menu = document.getElementById('popupmenu');
  menu.style.display='block'; //Showing the menu
  menu.style.left = latlong.x + x; //Positioning the menu
  menu.style.top = latlong.y + y;
...
do you othre stuff
...
}
```

and also use of  HTML5 you can do same thing easily.